# Python: "No such file or directory:" Exception

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I have encountered this error. I am currently in the same directory as the file, as shown in the image:
[Screenshot of Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYdUJ.png)

I have already checked the name of the file and even changed it, but it didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome! Please put the complete file path in `open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the path of python code and "kelimeler.txt" and use `file = open("kelimeler.txt", "r")` to open file correctly

"r" is read

you can learn more the mode in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)